# Passing t:savestate bean to another bean

Tags: jsf

I've two JSF 1.1 pages that I'm currently working with.  One of them is viewDevices.jsp and the other is vewDevicesPrint.jsp.  They are both running under the view scope (using tomahawk savestate, that is).  In viewDevices, it has a img that user can click on to go to the viewDevicesPrint.jsp.  Like so:

```
<img src="redesign/images/printicon2.png" alt="print records" border="0" width="16" height="16" onClick="javascript:window.open('/viewDevicesPrint.jsf','_blank','height=500,width=900,menubar=yes, toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes')"/>
```

When this img is clicked, I would like to pass the current instance of viewDevicesBean to the viewDevicesPrintBean.  Is there a way to do this?

I've the following in faces-config.xml.  In debug, viewDevicesPrintBean is getting a new instance of viewDevicesBean, instead of the current instance of it.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>viewDevicesPrintBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.arch.myaccount.jsf.ViewDevicesPrintBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param_viewDevicesBean</property-name>
        <value>#{viewDevicesBean}</value>
    </managed-property>  
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>viewDevicesBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.arch.myaccount.jsf.ViewDevicesBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param_flow</property-name>
        <value>#{param.Flow}</value>
</managed-property>  
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

A view scoped bean is tied to the current view. When you change the current view by navigating to a different view, then that different view would get a brand new instance of the view scoped bean. Note that it works also that way in JSF2.

Your best bet is to pass the desired data as request parameters in `window.open()` URL (escape them!), so that the print bean can get them as request parameters (via either managed property or `ExternalContext`). An alternative, especially if you've rather a lot of data, is to store the bean instance in the session scope under an unique and autogenerated key (e.g. `java.util.UUID`) and pass that key as request parameter so that the bean associated with the print page can obtain the data from the session scope by that key.

Comment: Thanks Balus.  I ended up makes viewDevicesPrint as a sub-view in viewDevices.  I then uses ajax to populate the sub-view when print button is clicked.  After that, I uses .html() to extract the sub-view and write it to a new window.open.  It works fine.  I'm curious to know if there is a way to code sub-view as a full html doc (with <html><head>.. tags)?